# DolphinDB: How to skip the value 0 in `avg` calculation?

Tags: null, average, dolphindb

How to skip the value 0 (or other value) in `avg` calculation? I don't want zero to participate in calculation like NULL does. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The NULL values are ignored in calculation when used as one of the arguments in function `avg` in dolphindb. Therefore, the following script is used to replace arguments (0 value in this case) to be skipped in calculation with Null value:

```
avg(iif(LastPx==0,NULL,LastPx))
```